# Form a relative path, going via a parent directory

Tags: filenames

My question is about relative addresses.  I need to create a relative address that goes upwards, then sideways, and then downwards.  Is this do-able?  Or am I required to use absolute addressing?  I prefer relative addressing, if it is possible.

This is my directory structure:  PUBLIC-A and PUBLIC-B are two root directories in my hosted account.  (These are 2 different Websites on the same hosted account.)

Public-A contains a directory called DIR-A, which has a file called aaa.php.

Public-B contains a directory called DIR-B, which has a file called bbb.php

I want bbb.php to do a php 'include' to get aaa.php.

In other words, bbb.php has to go 2 levels up (to reach Public-B), then 1 level across (to reach Public-A), then 1 level down (to reach to reach Dir-A).

Can this be done?  Is it possible to create a relative path that goes up, then sideways, then down?

Comment: Is your hosting account Shared??  This may not be possible if Apache has a VirtualHost directive for WEBSITE-A and WEBSITE-B.  If not,  try `..\..\PUBLIC-A\Dir-A\aaa.php`

Answer (score 2):

Why not? Just give the relative path. In your case, it should be

```
../../Public-A/DIR-A/aaa.php
```

There is no "sidewise" or other limits to relative paths.

Comment: I responded too soon.  The relative path syntax worked okay when I tested locally.  But when I tried it on the server (it is a shared server) it doesn't work.  So I am back to my initial problem:  Is there a way I can use a relative path that goes up, then sideways, then down?  This is a shared Apache server.

Comment: I mean to add:  On the server I also tried reversing the slashes, as in the other example given above.